# Installed BLT but trying to use hierbox gives "couldn't read file hierbox.tcl: no such file or directory"

Tags: tcl

I have installed BLT for tcl using an rpm and it looks like it's installed correctly.

From within wish I can successfully execute "package require BLT" but, if I try to do:

```
blt::hierbox .h
```

I get the following message:

> couldn't read file "hierbox.tcl": no such file or directory

I've looked in `/usr/lib64/blt2.4` and `heirbox.tcl` is there and doesn't seem to have any unusual permissions.

I guess that `pkgIndex.tcl` must be OK or the package require command would fail.

Interestingly, the graph widget from BLT seems to work fine: `blt::graph .g` works.

I don't know a lot about tcl (I'm just trying to get some legacy software to work) so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update** I have built BLT from source (which required also building tcl and tk 8.4 from source) and this seems to work. But only if I use bltwish which comes with it. There doesn't seem to a be bltwish exe with the rpm version of BLT which I've seen others complain about. Perhaps this is part of the problem.

In any case, I can work round it now so don't go to any effort to diagnose my previous problem unless anyone else is suffering too.

Answer (score 1):

On my Debian system, I'm using both Tcl 8.6 and 8.5 (the former as default), I've BLT2.4 installed using the standard debs, and if I run your same code, it works and creates the `hierbox` object.

```
$ wish
% package require BLT
2.4
% blt::hierbox .h
.h
%
```

BLT is installed in the `/usr/lib/blt2.4` directory, which contains the `pkgIndex.tcl` file and the `hierbox.tcl` file, so it seems the same as your condition (except for the results).

I gave a look into the `pkgIndex.tcl` file and it choose a binary library to load (located into `/usr/lib`), and load it using the Tcl `load` command. The declaration of the package is done by the shared object, so if `package require BLT` works, it needs to load the `.so` correctly.

Try to see whether the `graph.tcl` file is located inside the same directory as `hierbox.tcl`.

I've seen in the BTL sources that there is a `--with-blt` option to the `configure` script that tells where to put the BLT scripts. I think it is `/usr/lib/blt2.4` on my system, but maybe on yours it has be changed; then, if the rpm is wrong, it may install the `graph.tcl` file in the correct location given by the configuration option, but the `hierbox.tcl` in the wrong location, so that it doesn't work anymore.

Try the other widgets too, and see where the corresponding `.tcl` files are.

I can't say anything more than this, sorry :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already checked and graph.tcl is in the same place as hierbox.tcl. I also have an Ubuntu box with BLT installed and this works fine. I have tried comparing the pkgIndex.tcl files between teh two machines and they are a little different but I couldn't seem to get the Ubuntu one working on the other machine. In any case, my source build (which I configured with a --prefix option so it wasn't in the standard place) has worked fine.